# Pandas dataframe accessing and timeseries

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\user\Desktop\INTERNSHIP\SOLAR_DADRI\data.xlsx', 
index_col='Date/ Time')
pd.to_datetime(a.index)
a['Date/ Time']
```

I am getting a Key Error when i m trying to get a column which is there. The spacing is right. Also i am getting a error that i cannot convert string to float when i simply do plot(ts) which is the time or the x axis. 
Also when i try to see the type of index it says
     pandas.indexes.base.Index

Comment: so `a['Date/ Time` displays the column as expected?

Comment: No it shows a key error

Answer (score 1):

When you use parameter `index_col`, you move that column into the index.  In single index dataframe you access to what was in this column using 'a.index' in  your example.  If you use `a.reset_index()` and move that index back into columns, you should be able to then access that column using `a['Date/ Time']`.

Comment: Thank you. So i am to understand that in a single index dataframe i cannot output the index column using a[] and must do a.index

Comment: Correct, you access the index as a.index.

Comment: @Anshitsingh Would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) this answer if it helped you.